# i want to save the user input data to a file this is what i have done. the solution execute but the file is not created

Tags: xaml

private async void submit_comment(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String input = txtInput.Text;

```
        //getting the DocumentsLibrary folder where a file is to be created and then creating the example.txt file 
        //and storing the StorageFile object that is returned:
        try
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
            //Writing to file
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, input);
        }catch(Exception)
        {

        }





    }
```

Comment: You have to use `CreateFileAsync` instead of `GetFileAsync`. You might have realized that by yourself if you did not have an empty catch block. That catches all exception and does nothing with them. So any potential error is simply ignored.